# 3D console game distance detection not working properly

Tags: python, console

I am trying to make a 3D game in a python console. There aren't any errors but when I run it, it doesn't show anything (which is fine) because it doesn't detect any blocks (#) in the players view (not fine).

The problem is probably around line 78, which is always `True` (on the first distance check of the ray) and I don't know why (that's my problem). I will of course add player-movement and a map that's more complex. At the moment the player just rotates right at a hardcoded speed.

```
import os
import time
import math
import threading


hardMap = [   #exists so I can edit it
    ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#"],
    ["#",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","#","#"],
    ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"]

    ]


gameMap = "".join(["".join(hardMap[n]) for n in range(len(hardMap))])

notDone = True

playerX = 2
playerY = 2
playerA = 0 #player angle --> +1 turn right; -1 turn left

fov = 4
fov = math.pi / fov

depth = 20

fps = 30

screenWidth = 120
screenHeight = 40
os.system(f'mode con: cols={screenWidth} lines={screenHeight}')

screen = [" " for n in range(screenHeight * screenWidth)]
mapWidth = len(gameMap[0])
mapHeight = len(gameMap)



def printScreen(string):
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(0.01)  # reduce flickering
    for x in [string[i:i+screenWidth] for i in range(0,len(string),screenWidth)]:
        print("".join(x))
    

while(notDone):
    
    playerA = playerA + 0.01
    startTime = time.time()
    for x in range(screenWidth):
        rayAngle = (playerA - fov / 2) + ((x / screenWidth) * fov)
        distanceToWall = 0
        hitWall = False

        eyeX = math.sin(rayAngle)
        eyeY = math.cos(rayAngle)

        while not hitWall and distanceToWall < depth:
            distanceToWall += 0.1
            
            testX = int(playerX + eyeX * distanceToWall)
            testY = int(playerY + eyeY * distanceToWall)


            distanceBeforTheIf = distanceToWall


            if testX < 0 or testX >= mapWidth or testY < 0 or testY>= mapHeight: #---------------THE PROBLEM------------
                hitWall = True
                distanceToWall = depth
                with open("log.txt","a") as f:
                        f.write(f"angle: {playerA}\ndistanceToWall:{distanceToWall}\ndistanceBeforTheIf :{distanceBeforTheIf}")
                        
            elif gameMap[testY * mapWidth + testX] == "#":    
                    hitWall = True
                
                
        ceiling = int((screenHeight / 2.0) - (screenHeight / distanceToWall))
        floor = screenHeight - ceiling  

        for y in range(screenHeight):

    
            if distanceToWall <= depth / 4: shade = u"\u2591"
            elif distanceToWall < depth / 3: shade = u"\u2592"
            elif distanceToWall < depth / 2: shade = u"\u2593"
            elif distanceToWall < depth / 1: shade = u"\u2588"
            else: shade = " "

            
            if y < ceiling:
                screen[y * ceiling + x] = " "
            elif y > ceiling and y <= floor:
                screen[y * screenWidth + x] = shade
            else:
                screen[y * screenWidth + x] = " "
    printScreen(screen)           
    time.sleep(max(1./fps - (time.time() - startTime), 0))
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you may want to remove comma (`,`) after the last sublist in `hardMap`.

Comment: Please specify or indicate more clear where the error is — most folks aren't going to try to figure out what "around line 78" means.

Comment: @martineau it's commented as `#---------------THE PROBLEM------------`

Comment: If you step through the code line-by-line in a debugger, what are the values of `testX`, `testY`, `mapWidth` and `mapHeight`? That should explain why that statement is always returning `True`.

Comment: @Random: In that case the OP should have mentioned it IMO.

Comment: Oh, the values for mapWidth and mapHeight are 1 and 256. Do you know why? Edit: I know. The `hardMap` used to be called `gameMap` but i had to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now works. The `hardMap` was previously called `gameMap` but I changed it due to wanting a 1d array but still an option to easily change the map. I just changed:
`mapWidth = len(gameMap[0]) mapHeight = len(gameMap)`
to
`mapWidth = len(hardMap[0]) mapHeight = len(hardMap)`

Thanks Random Davis!